# Solve the first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Following the hint, I attempted making the above equation homogenous, but I couldn't figure out how to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $(\ln y)'= \frac{y'}{y}$. Hence, if you use the hint and if you put $z= \ln y$, then you get the equation

$z'=-1-\frac{1}{x}z$

Comment: All too easy.  Well done Fred.  (+1) ... I would say that the "hint" is a bit misleading.  It should read, "Divide both sides of the equation by $y$."

Comment: @Fred Why is the answer z' = ...? Doesn't solving the differential equation mean that the answer should be y = ...? Also, how did you come up with (lny)' = y'/y? I don't think I would be able to guess that on a test

Comment: So how to solve this diff eq for z? (assuming prime means derivative w.r.t. x)

Comment: @lalala This can be solved using an [Integrating Factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html) or with [Variation of Parameters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters).